# Convert Video or audio to text without playing it?

Tags: java, audio, video, text, speech-recognition

Is there any reference through which we could convert an audio or video file to a text file (opposite of text to speach) in java. 
I have checked it with [here](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/) but I didnt find any solution that can convert to text without playing it

Answer (score 1):

I not too sure what type you looking for, but you can find more [here](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/speech/forDevelopers/jsapifaq.html#implementation)  and the other not listed is [here](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/). Hope this helps

Comment: In simple words the question is how to transcript any audio without playing it. The project doesnt solve that problem

Comment: So is your question about how to 'extract' what's being said in the file to text?

Comment: *"any audio without playing it."*  If an API can do speech recognition, it should be able to do it for a sound file provided without 'playing it out loud' to the end user.  The API will still need to read it though, and 'listen' to the sound.  There is no magic for getting around that.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: Thats what i am trying to find out ;)

Comment: *"Thats what i am trying to find out"*  Well I'll tell you again.  No there isn't such a way.

Comment: But Andrew's earlier comment is correct. You don't need to "play" the audio file through a media player and actually convert it to sound. Something like CMUSPhinx can read the audio file as data and convert it to text without ever creating actual sound. It can do this faster than real time and in parallel, so you could convert batches of audio files to text faster than you could play all the files through a media player.